# Got Error: TokenCreate has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle-console

**truffle.js**

```
module.exports =  {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*" // Match any network id
        }
    }
};
```

**2_deploy_tokenCreate.js**

```
const TokenCreate = artifacts.require('./TokenCreate.sol');

const NewToken = artifacts.require('./NewToken.sol');[![enter image description here][1]][1]


module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // Use deployer to state migration tasks.
  const openingTime = web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp + 2; // two secs in the future

  const closingTime = openingTime + 86400 * 20; // 20 days

  const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000);

  const wallet = accounts[[1]];



  return deployer

      .then(() => {

          return deployer.deploy(NewToken);

      })

      .then(() => {

          return deployer.deploy(

              TokenCreate,

              openingTime,

              closingTime,

              rate,

              wallet,

              NewToken.address

          );

      });
};
```

**TokenCreate.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

import "./NewToken.sol";

import "../../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";

import "../../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol";

contract TokenCreate is MintedCrowdsale,TimedCrowdsale {

    constructor() 
        Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token) 
        TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)  
    {
        uint256 _openingTime;
        uint256 _closingTime;
        uint256 _rate;
        address _wallet;
        MintableToken _token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly elaborate more so that it will be helpful to understand what issue you are facing. Provide codes of smart contract as well.

Comment: I updated it ! kindly review it! @asvisosila

Answer (score 1):

I have got my mistake! I have migrated NewToken instead of TokenCreate! so the right one is to migrate TokenCreate!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because truffle is not able to find artifacts of smart contract `TokenCreate.sol`.

I think you need to install Zeppelin Solidity library locally to compile smart contract TokenCreate.

Install it first using the command

```
npm install zeppelin-solidity@1.7.0
```

Refer the following blog to understand how to create token and initial coin offering contracts using truffle and zeppelin solidity.

https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6

Comment: I have already installed zeppelin-solidity using this command! still got this error!@asvisosila

Comment: Can you tell the list JSON files in the build folder of your repository

Comment: Json files in build folder are =>**BasicToken.json , Crowdsale.json, ERC20.json, ERC20Basic.json, Migrations.json, MintableToken.json, MintedCrowdsale.json, NewToken.json, Ownable.json, safeMath.json, StandardToken.json, TimedCrowdsale.json, TokenCreate.json ** @asvisosila

Comment: Delete all the JSON files stored build folder and execute truffle migrate command again or execute truffle migrate --reset  command

Comment: I tried it! but still error remains the same!! @asvisosila